# Hessenberg matrix

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-decomposition

Modify the factorization algorithm $LU$ to efficiently factorize a Hessenberg matrix
where factorization algorithm $LU$ is

```
function [A] = lu_kji (A)

    [n,n]=size(A);

    for k=1:n-1
        A(k+1:n,k)=A(k+1:n,k)/A(k,k);
        for j=k+1:n
            for i=k+1:n
                A(i,j)=A(i,j)-A(i,k)*A(k,j);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Help me please whit HINT, 
thanks for your helping me.

Comment: Just pick up some arbitrary hessenberg matrix and apply the algorithm to it. Make some observations

Comment: If pick $ k+1=2$? Is correct?